Why am I getting an error when deleting the last element in an array of objects
My app has a list of items which the user can select their favorites from. The selected favorites are added to an array of objects one by one as the user selects them like so:
dispatch(
  addFavorite({
    id: currentIndex,
    title: getIds[currentIndex].title,
    liked: 'true',
  }),
);

The problem occurs when I want to delete the items one by one. If I try and delete the last object in the array I get an error "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".
If I have for example:
  selectedFavorites: [
    {
      title: '',
      id: '',
      liked: '',
    },
    
    {
     title: 'First Title'
     id: 1,
     liked: true,

    },
    {
     title: 'Second Title'
     id: 2,
     liked: true,
    },
  ],

I will get an error when trying to delete the last object but am able to delete any previous objects without error.
In my redux file I'm removing the items using filter:
removeFavorite: (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedFavorites: state.selectedFavorites.filter(
      fav => fav.id !== action.payload,
    ),
  };
},

The action is called with this function:
  const handlePress = () => {
    dispatch(removeFavorite(getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].id));
  };

And I'm mapping and rendering the favorites like so:
const getFavoriteTitles = getFavorites.selectedFavorites.map((f, index) => {
    return f;
  });

    return (
           <View>
            <Text>            
              {getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].title}
            </Text> 
           </View>
            )

I've tried to condense this as much as possible but please let me know if you would like to see more of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've also tried rendering components conditionally with various checks like this:
if (
    getFavorites.selectedFavorites.some(
      el => el.id === getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].id,
    )
    // getFavoriteTitles.length
    // getFavoriteTitles.length > 0
    // getFavoriteTitles[favoriteIndex].title.length > 0
  ) {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={lightGlobalStyles.flex}>
          <Animated.View
            <Text
              style={[
                style.favoritesText,
                theme.theme === true
                  ? themes.whiteText
                  : theme.theme2 === true
                  ? themes.yellowText
                  : theme.theme5 === true
                  ? themes.darkText
                  : themes.offWhiteText,
              ]}>
              {getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].title}
            </Text>
         
          </Animated.View>
        <Background />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={lightGlobalStyles.flex}>
        <View>
          <Text
            style={[
              style.favoritesText,
              theme.theme === true
                ? themes.whiteText
                : theme.theme2 === true
                ? themes.yellowText
                : theme.theme5 === true
                ? themes.darkText
                : themes.offWhiteText,
            ]}>
            No favorites selected
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Background />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }


You need to show how you set and update currentIndex, but my guess would be that currentIndex points to the last item in the array and after you remove that it points to a non-existing entry, so getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex] returns undefined. So you need to make sure currentIndex is handled properly.

current index is set up like this  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0), Would it make sense to change to null and do some sort of check to see if there is a current index. if(currentIndex !== null) then fire the delete function?

I agree with @Lennholm, you remove the last array element by index, and so afterwards, the index is no longer valid. You should handle this appropriately/accordingly. There are multiple ways to handle this and none is more or less correct than any other, so whichever solution you choose is up to you and your specific use cases.

It seems after much trial and error I'm still confused with this. I've added some things I've tried to my original question but nothing I've tried seems to get at the concept of what to do when the last element is deleted

I have found one solution. I simply set currentIndex back to 0 after dispatch(removeFavorite)                                                                                                             const handlePress = () => {
dispatch(removeFavorite(getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].id));
setCurrentIndex(0);
}; Thanks Lennholm and Drew for the tips!

This is one solution:
  const handlePress = () => {
    dispatch(removeFavorite(getFavoriteTitles[currentIndex].id));
    setCurrentIndex(0);
  };

